# Graphite whisper losing old data

Tags: metrics, graphite, statsd, grafana, whisper

My graphite whisper databases don't store data older than 7 days old. Using the `whisper-fetch.py` tool I can only see data up to 1 week back (when there should be data for at least 3 weeks at this point). I'm using grafana, statsd, graphite-web, carbon and whisper.

An example of one of the metrics being truncated:

`stats.counters.api.create_order.pc.chrome`

This is my `storage-schemas.conf`:

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 10s:6h,1min:90d

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 10s:6h,1min:6d,10min:5y
```

And here is my `storage-aggregation.conf`:

```
[min]
pattern = \.lower$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = min

[max]
pattern = \.upper(_\d+)?$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = max

[sum]
pattern = \.sum$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[count]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[count_legacy]
pattern = ^stats_counts.*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[default_average]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0.3
aggregationMethod = average
```

Comment: can you use whisper-info to get the expected retention of data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. Using `whisper-info.py`, the retention times were shown to be 7 days on all the old metrics, as I was witnessing. Newer metrics were being retained just fine. The current `storage-schemas.conf` didn't have 7 days specified anywhere... but the previous `storage-schemas.conf` file could have had it.

It seems graphite does not automatically update the whisper files for new retention times specified in `storage-schemas.conf` I used the `whisper-resize.py` tool to manually resize all the old metric whisper files, and now `whisper-info.py` shows the right retention periods.

Comment: yes indeed, graphite does not change retention on the fly.